# How do I add an image as an icon in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

So I am pretty new to react native. I have been working on a project lately and I have made an icon that I want to put on top of my react native application (along with the heading). It is a png image. Following is my main screen code.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
    View,
    Text,
    StyleSheet,
    Platform
} from "react-native";

import HomeTab from './AppTabNavigator/HomeTab'
import SearchTab from './AppTabNavigator/SearchTab'
import AddMediaTab from './AppTabNavigator/AddMediaTab'
import LikesTab from './AppTabNavigator/LikesTab'
import ProfileTab from './AppTabNavigator/ProfileTab'

import { createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation'
import { Icon } from 'native-base'

class MainScreen extends Component {
    static navigationOptions = {

        title: "AaROGYA SAMAJ",    //This is the heading
        headerTintColor: '#000000',
        headerAlignement: "center",
        headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: '#8dbef5',
          },
          headerTitleStyle: {
            fontSize: 18,
            fontWeight: "bold",
            alignItems: "center",
            justifyContent: "center",
          },
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <AppTabNavigator />
        );
    }
}

export default MainScreen;

const AppTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({

    Feeds: {
        screen: HomeTab
    },

    TagDumpingSite: {
        screen: AddMediaTab
    },

    Community: {
        screen: LikesTab
    },

    Profile: {
        screen: ProfileTab
    },

}, {
        animationEnabled: true,
        swipeEnabled: true,
        tabBarPosition: "bottom",
        tabBarOptions: {
            style: {
                ...Platform.select({
                    android: {
                        backgroundColor: '#8dbef5'
                    }
                })
            },
            activeTintColor: '#000',
            inactiveTintColor: '#1113a4',
            showLabel: true,
            showIcon: true
        }
    })

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#7078f7',

    },
});
```

As you can see, "AaROGYA SAMAJ" is the heading name of my application. Just along this heading I want to add the image(logo or icon) which I have in a folder. Can anyone help ?
 ps: I want to put it in center of the navigation tab.

Answer (score -5):

Can't help much without more info by I guess this might help?
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image